# Data type is preventing relationship creation in Access

Tags: database, vba, validation, ms-access, relational-database

So I have a table named "Client" where the ClientID is the Primary Key and the Data Type is an AutoNumber, but I formatted it as \C00 so instead of "001" or "002" the record appears as "C001" or "C002".

I expected Access to essentially change the data type from AutoNumber to Short Text because of the formatting, since it's basically concatenation.

So the issue comes when trying to create a relationship between ClientID in the Client table and ClientID in any other, because I have the Data Type set as Short Text everywhere else.

Is there a way around this? I can't have the primary key for all of my tables be auto-generated alone, I need them to have a letter prefix. Unless someone can suggest a more efficient manner of accomplishing that.

Thanks folks!

Comment: you need to separate the autonumber function from the display purpose.  You need a numeric (long integer) field for referential integrity purposes, but when you're displaying the ID on a report (prettyID), then you can append your prefix.  Don't store your ID pretty, just display it pretty.

Comment: My only concern is that this will be utilized by our data entry team, so a tiny discretion in appearance and the back end may cause issues. It was explicitly requested of me that I include the prefix "c" or whatever other letter denotes the table content. I've changed all of my foreign key fields to Number data type, and it's working for now, but I'm not sure if it's the optimal solution.

Comment: no, if you're using the column's property to 'pretty' your output, you should be good, but the underlying data type is numeric across the board.  Access is basically making it easy for you.

Comment: yes it is the optimal solution. leave it as auto-number and change other table's fields as number. it should be fine!

Comment: Create a new table `NextClientId`, with a single column `ClientID` and a constraint to ensure there can never be more than one row in this table. Insert that one row using the value of the next unused `ClientID` in the sequence e.g. `C0003`. Now you need some procedural code that 1) locks the row/table, 2) grabs the stored `ClientID` value (`C0003`) into a variable, 3) increments the stored `ClientID` value (`C0004`), 4) unlocks the row/table, 5) returns the grabbed value (`C0003`). You can't do this in an Access SQL stored procedure, but maybe in one of those new trigger macro thingys?